# Activity don't display fab icon on android 4.4 kitkat

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I have a simple fab icon in my activity, it works fine in android 7.0 but I can't see the fab when I run my app on android 4.4, I tried changing attributes of fab but nothing worked.

here is my xml code

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:id="@+id/fab1"
    app:fabSize="mini"/>

<FrameLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/srl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <user.app.CustomWebView
            android:id="@+id/web1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</FrameLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here is my activity.

```
public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

FloatingActionButton fab1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

    fab1 = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab1);

    fab1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(TestActivity.this, "you just clicked the fab", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fab is being hidden by your framelayout. Place the fab below it in the XML so it is layered on top instead of underneath it.

It is visible in android 7 because of the material layout elevation effect